# Trigger mysql whenever two fields are equal

Tags: mysql

Supposing I have three fields **number**, **decimal** and **hundreds**. What I'd like to do is `SET hundreds='100'` whenever both decimal and number are equal to **10**. I've tried the following but failed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE table SET hundreds='100' WHERE  decimal = hundreds;
```

Comment: @scrowler thank you for the support to this newbie! :p

Comment: you need a trigger, or you just want to update your table?

Comment: @fthiella I would like to update the table whenever both fields are equal... the thing is **number** and **decimal** will be constantly changing through an ajax request or SSEvent from 5 to 5 seconds, getting higher or lower. I would prefer to create a trigger and update if possible then query the values, compare them and after query again to update...

Comment: Hey new user, I think it would be fine to introduce you to the [REFMAN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html) ;)

You may prefer to know specifically about [Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html). Have fun.

Comment: @leonardo_assumpcao hey leonardo, thank you very much for this helpful tip!!! I've studied that before, thank you!!!!!!!! But as a "new user" as you might have guessed, the concepts of "before and after" can get a little fuzzy!! :SSSS But I bet you, whom has linked me to REFMAN and could point another 20.000 websites instead of helping me directly and get me to understand how to perform this particular trigger would also be able to answer flawlessly! Give it a try? If you are correct you even win points, wonderful!

Comment: Oh new user. Don't be mad.